# Getting the percent of a column related to the entire sum of a column sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the percent of the yearly forecast column related to the overall total forecast for a specific product NDC. I have the code below but it is returning the value 0 every time. Any ideas?

```
     select 
    f.ProductNDC ProductNDC,
    g.IMDSC1 ItemDesc,
    g.IMDSC2 ItemDesc2,
    cf.DirectUsage YearlyForecast,
    (cf.DirectUsage  / (SUM(cf.DirectUsage) over(partition by f.ProductNDC))),
    cd.CustomerNum CustomerNumber,
    cd.CustomerName CustomerName,
    cf.EffectiveDate EffectiveDate,
    cf.EndDate EndDate
From Forecast_Dev.dbo.Forecast f
    join Forecast_Dev.dbo.CustomerForecast cf 
        on cf.ForecastID = f.ForecastID
    join Forecast_Dev.dbo.CustomerDetail cd
        on cd.CustomerID = cf.CustomerID
    join JDE_DEVELOPMENT.TESTDTA.F4101 g
        on ltrim(rtrim(g.imlitm))= f.ProductNDC
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `DirectUsage `

Comment: @Prdp the data type is int

Comment: So integer division is happening. Gordan answer should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some databases do integer division, meaning that the ratio of two integers is an integer.  So, 1 / 2 = 0, rather than 0.5.

So, turn this to a floating point number of some sort:

```
(cf.DirectUsage * 1.0 / nullif(SUM(cf.DirectUsage) over(partition by f.ProductNDC))), 0),
```

Comment: Better to add `NULLIF` in *denominator* to avoid *Divide by zero* execption